# Laravel authentication routing after click login button

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel-5

I have 2 Laravel application inside `var/www/html` directory.
In the address bar, if we type `localhost/first` the Laravel authentication will be displayed and the URL is `http://localhost/first/public/auth/login` but after i click `submit` button the URL become `http://localhost/auth/login` and it shows a error:

```
The requested URL /auth/login was not found on this server.
```

can you suggest me what is wrong?

Comment: It is to do with the htaccess and how URL's are rewritten, you want to get each laravel installation on it's own sub domain ideally.

Answer (score 0):

In the form you have the post url as `/auth/login`

Just keep post url as blank or give complete path in the `form open` tag `/first/public/auth/login`.

If `/` is there it will take the path from the root rather than going relative to the app root.

Can give correct update if you can post your login form's blade template also with the question

Comment: Thank you for your reply..I got the solution..Previously in my view , after clicking login button my post URL will be /auth/login , so only it will case the problem, now i have changed to login instead of /auth/login, now my problem is solved.